# How to efficiently check if a list of consecutive numbers is missing any elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have this array

```
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
```

I was trying to find an algorithm that will tell me which `s`s are missing. As you can see, the list consists of consecutive `s`s (`s1`, `s2`, etc.).

At first I went with this solution:

```js
    var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
for (var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    var thisI = parseInt(arr[i].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]);
    var prevI = parseInt(arr[i-1].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]);
    if (thisI != prevI+1)
      console.log(`Seems like ${prevI+1} is missing. thisI is ${thisI} and prevI is ${prevI}`)
}
```

But this method fails for more than one consecutive numbers missing (`s15`, `s16`). So I added a `while` loop which works.

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
for (var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
  var thisI = parseInt(arr[i].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]);
  var prevI = parseInt(arr[i-1].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]);
  if (thisI != prevI+1) {
    while(thisI-1 !== prevI++){
       console.log(`Seems like ${prevI} is missing. thisI is ${thisI} and prevI is ${prevI}`)
    }
   }
}
```

However, I feel like I'm overly complicating things.
I thought of creating an ideal array:

```
var idealArray = [];
for (var i =0; i<200;i++) {
  idealArray.push(i)
}
```

And then, while checking, tamper with my array (`arr`) so that the loop checks two arrays of the same length. I.e., use this solution:

```js
var idealArray = [];
for (var i =0; i<200;i++) {
  idealArray.push(i)
}
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
for (let i = 0; i<idealArray.length;i++){
  if (parseInt(arr[i].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]) != idealArray[i]) {
    console.log(`Seems like ${idealArray[i]}is missing`);
    arr.splice(i,0,"dummyel")
  }
}
```

But, once again, I have the feeling that creating this second array is not very efficient either (thinking of a big list, I'd waste unnecessary space).

So... how do I efficiently perform this task in JavaScript? (Efficiently meaning as close to O(1) as possible both for time complexity and for space complexity.)

Comment: Hmm, my first thought would be to do a naive linear search. Basically, start a counter with the first number in the array, then go through the array incrementing the counter and checking it against the current element. Obviously, that's O(n), though. For a more efficient solution, I suppose you can do something with binary chops - take the first number, the last number and the array length - do these match up? If not, take half the array and do the same process. Repeat until you find the missing element. Needs some work for multiple missing members but is O(log n) in execution but not space.

Comment: @TanDuong I was under the impression that Code Review isn't about coming up with a better algorithm but just polishing the existing solution. Unless you've tried to reinvent the wheel instead of using a built in functionality or something.

Comment: Can you assume that the number `k` of missing elements grows strictly slower than `O(N)`, where `N` is the size of the range? If you can give a stronger upper bound on `k` (e.g. something like `log(N)` or `sqrt(N)` or `N^\alpha` for some `\alpha < 1.0`), then algorithms with worst case behavior better than `O(N)` could be possible.

Comment: Do you also need to check for overlaps e.g. `["s00", "s01", "s01", "s03"]`?

Comment: @SalmanA No, no need to check for overlaps. The input is guaranteed to contain distinctive consecutive numbers in ascending order;  pnuts you're right... I meant which ss are missing indeed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you know you are expecting a sequential array, I don't know why it needs to be more complicated than a loop through numbers `arr[0]` through `arr[end]` while keeping a counter to know where you are in the array. This will run at O(n), but I don't think you can improve on that — you need to look at every element at least once in the worst case.

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];

let first = parseInt(arr[0].substring(1))
let last =  parseInt(arr[arr.length-1].substring(1))
let count = 0
for (let i = first; i< last; i++) {
   if (parseInt(arr[count].substring(1)) == i) {count++; continue}
   else console.log(`seem to be missing ${'s'+i.toString().padStart(2,'0')} between: ${arr[count-1]} and ${arr[count]}` )
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

After thinking a bit about the comments below, I made a recursive approach that splits the array and checks each half. Mostly as an experiment, not as a practical solution. This does in fact run with fewer than `n` iterations in most cases, but I couldn't find a case where it was actually faster Also, I just pushed indexes showing where the gaps are to make the structure easier to see and test. <s>And as you'll see, because it's recursive the results aren't in order.</s>

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];

let missingGaps = []

function missing(arr, low, high) {
  if (high <= low) return

  let l = parseInt(arr[low].substring(1))
  let h = parseInt(arr[high].substring(1))

  if (h - l == high - low) return
  if (high - low === 1) {
    missingGaps.push([low, high])
    return
  } else {
    let mid = ((high - low) >> 1) + low
    
    missing(arr, low, mid)

    // need to check case where split might contain gap
    let m = parseInt(arr[mid].substring(1))
    let m1 = parseInt(arr[mid + 1].substring(1))
    if (m1 - m !== 1) missingGaps.push([mid, mid + 1])

    missing(arr, mid + 1, high)
  }
}

missing(arr, 0, arr.length-1)
missingGaps.forEach(g => console.log(`missing between indices ${arr[g[0]]} and ${arr[g[1]]}`))
```

Maybe another answer or comment will have an improvement that makes it a bit faster.

Comment: `This will run at O(n), but I don't think you can improve on that` As I mentioned in a comment, you should be able to bring it down to O(log n). You can only do a linear scan for small sections of the array, and binary chop the big ones, discarding any sections that don't have missing numbers. E.g., if you narrow down to `["s00","s01","s02","s03"]` you will know there is nothing missing because the first element is `0`, the last one is `3` and the length is `4` - that means there is nothing missing. Admittendly, its more work to implement but it is faster for large arrays.

Comment: @vlaz I was just thinking about that. It's clear that it improves best cases (for example when there's no missing numbers), but I'm not sure how to evaluate the worst case.

Comment: For @vlaz's algo, It's more accurate to measure complexity in terms of both the size of the array (N) and the number of missing elements to be identified (M). Every missing element needs to be printed and each missing element can be found in O(log N). So the worst case time is O(M log N). However, in very sparse arrays the missing elements are going to be in spans; in this case, an entire span can be found in O(log N). If S is the number of spans, the complexity is O(M + S log N). Since S <= N + 1, the worst case is O(M + N log N). (O(M) is to print the missing elements.) Also, S <= M, fwiw.

Comment: @rici, I've been thinking about this and I wonder when exactly is O(M log N) better than O(N). If M is always going to be about 25% of N as in the example, O(N) is significantly better than O(M log N) except for arrays or length less than 16. After than O(N) becomes much better as the array grows. Am I thinking about something backward?

Comment: M log N is better than N if M is "a lot" smaller than N. So if missing keys are the exception (as they would be in many use cases), go for @vlaz's approach. (But the constant factor is bigger and it isn't particularly cache-friendly, so the expected size of M would have to be a lot smaller than the simple computation might indicate.)

Comment: Also, it's easy to get the missing values in order. In your code, for example, you could do the "gap in the split" test *in between* the recursive calls, rather than before them.

Comment: Finally, you compute `parseInt(arr[low].substring(1))` four times in each call, but once is sufficient (assuming passing an additional argument is cheaper than that computation, which seems likely to me).

Comment: @Mark_M yeah, that's it. With many gaps it becomes a bit more complicated but you can still avoid chunks of the array and only do the search where you know there are missing parts. Then again, you need to account for something like, say, getting a split that results in something like `[1, 2]` and `[4, 5]` - each of these is correct but `3` is still missing.

Comment: Just coded this solution on an airplane flight and was about to post it when landed :) (anyway I voted up before you added it)

Answer (score 6):

As I understand from your ideal array solution, you know the maximum array size(?). So if you have 100 maximum values and expect S00 - S99 you can do:

```
var arrayIndex=0;
for (var i =0; i<100;i++) {
   var idealValue="s"+("00"+i).slice(-2); // To get S01-S99
   if(arr.length <= arrayIndex || arr[arrayIndex]!=idealValue){
        console.log(idealValue + 'is missing');
   }
   arrayIndex++;
}
```

Or something like that. I can't test it right now ;) But iterate through the list of ideal values and compare the same value in the array. If it doesn't match print it.

Comment: Yes, I know the maximum array length as I know the value of the top most item. I don't know why I haven't thought of this. While this could be the accepted answer, there's an even better one that I will accept, but it's a great simple solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution with the inner `while`-loop seems already quite good, just omit the unnecessary `if`, and keep track of the number that you are currently expecting to see instead of parsing the previous number every time.

Something like this:

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
var expectedI = 0
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var currentI = parseInt(arr[i].toLowerCase().split("s")[1]);
  while (expectedI < currentI) {
    console.log(`Seems like ${expectedI} is missing.`)
    expectedI++
  }
  expectedI = currentI + 1
}
```

gives you:

```
Seems like 6 is missing.
Seems like 15 is missing.
Seems like 16 is missing.
Seems like 18 is missing.
Seems like 23 is missing.
Seems like 29 is missing.
Seems like 31 is missing.
Seems like 35 is missing.
Seems like 37 is missing.
Seems like 40 is missing.
Seems like 42 is missing.
Seems like 57 is missing.
Seems like 59 is missing.
Seems like 66 is missing.
Seems like 68 is missing.
```

The idea is very simple: if you don't see the number that you expected to see, print it to console (or save it elsewhere), then continue with the next number.

Note that you can't get the runtime below `O(N)`, because you have to look at every element of the list at least once, and it could also happen that you have to print `O(N)` missing elements to the console.

The above algorithm looks at every element of the list once, and can function with constant space overhead.

**EDIT:** The [comment made by vlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274554/how-to-efficiently-check-if-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers-is-missing-any-element/50275051#comment87571599_50277123) seems to propose an algorithm that should work faster for arrays with few gaps. However, this still does not change the worst case behavior, because in the worst case (if everything is missing), you still have to print all `N` numbers. If you assume that the number `k` of missing numbers is "much smaller" than `N` (i.e. `k` not in `Theta(N)`), then more efficient algorithms could be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array by taking two elements  of the array and fill the gaps, if exists.

```js
const
    getNumber = s => +s.slice(1),
    pad = i => ('00' + i).slice(-2);

var array = ["s00", "s01", "s02", "s03", "s04", "s05", "s07", "s08", "s09", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s17", "s19", "s20", "s21", "s22", "s24", "s25", "s26", "s27", "s28", "s30", "s32", "s33", "s34", "s36", "s38", "s39", "s41", "s43", "s44", "s45", "s46", "s47", "s48", "s49", "s50", "s51", "s52", "s53", "s54", "s55", "s56", "s58", "s60", "s61", "s62", "s63", "s64", "s65", "s67", "s69", "s70"],
    result = [];

array.reduce((left, right) => {
    var l = getNumber(left),
        r = getNumber(right);

    while (++l < r) {
        result.push('s' + pad(l));
    }
    return right;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the same solution the OP already implemented just using more built-in functions and succinct code. OP asked for possibly more efficient "time complexity and...space complexity."

Comment: @גלעדברקן, basically any code would iterate the given array and would fill the gaps. so, what is the question for?

Comment: I'm not sure, but one possible answer is that there is no more efficient solution than something like this :)

Comment: @SalmanA, unary plus and `slice` has nothing to do with golfing.

Comment: @NinaScholz using `Number` to cast and a more appropriate string functions is easier to understand for novice.

Comment: @SalmanA, `slice` is the more comprehensible method for iterables to get only a part of it. `substr` is a special case and imho should be not used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an approach to find if, in given array, some element in a number sequence is missing. We could use (n*(n+1))/2 that resolve addition on n first numbers. Also, If the array starts with for example 10 we remove 1-10 sum. This just telling us if something is missing, but not what is missing.  The advantage is that the array could be unsorted. Calculate minimum is less expensive than order the entire array.

```
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];

let total = 0;

for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i].replace("s", ""));
    total += arr[i];
}

let hipFirstSum = ((arr[0]-1)*(arr[0]))/2;  //or minimun
let n = arr[arr.length -1];
let hipSum = (n*(n+1))/2;
let realSum = hipSum - hipFirstSum;

(realSum != total)?console.log("wrong"):console.log("good");
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of summing up everything. That definitely works with unsorted arrays. Still, the question is to find what's missing and unfortunately this code doesn't address that.

Comment: @valz I know, this could be a solution for some other situation. When I read the question first time, I thought what happen if we don't know if the array is sorted?

Comment: This solution is far too complicated. You don't have to sum everything. You actually just need to find the min and max value. These values will tell you how many elements should be there and you can just compare it with the length of the array. If the array is sorted, that means just taking `a[0]` and `a[a.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can go for something like this that compares each array item to the one next to it then if the difference is greater than 1 display all the numbers in between can be logged.

```js
const arr = ["s00", "s01", "s02", "s03", "s04", "s05", "s07", "s08", "s09", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s17", "s19", "s20", "s21", "s22", "s24", "s25", "s26", "s27", "s28", "s30", "s32", "s33", "s34", "s36", "s38", "s39", "s41", "s43", "s44", "s45", "s46", "s47", "s48", "s49", "s50", "s51", "s52", "s53", "s54", "s55", "s56", "s58", "s60", "s61", "s62", "s63", "s64", "s65", "s67", "s69", "s70"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  let currentNum = parseInt(arr[i].split("s")[1]);
  let difference = parseInt(arr[i + 1].split("s")[1]) - currentNum;
  if (difference === 1) continue

  for (let d = 1; d < difference; d++)
    console.log(`Seems likes ${currentNum+d} is missing`)
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the recursive approach based on accepted answer but refactored to *return* the data:

```js
var arr = ["s00", "s01", "s02", "s03", "s04", "s05", "s07", "s08", "s09", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s17", "s19", "s20", "s21", "s22", "s24", "s25", "s26", "s27", "s28", "s30", "s32", "s33", "s34", "s36", "s38", "s39", "s41", "s43", "s44", "s45", "s46", "s47", "s48", "s49", "s50", "s51", "s52", "s53", "s54", "s55", "s56", "s58", "s60", "s61", "s62", "s63", "s64", "s65", "s67", "s69", "s70"];

function findMissing(arr, l, r) {
  var lval = Number(arr[l].substr(1));
  var rval = Number(arr[r].substr(1));
  // the segment has no gaps
  if (r - l === rval - lval) {
    return [];
  }
  // the segment has exactly two items
  if (r - l === 1) {
    return Array.from({ length: rval - lval - 1 }, function(x, i) {
      return "s" + (lval + 1 + i);
    });
  }
  // calculate middle using integer cast trick
  var m = (l + r) / 2 | 0;
  // process the segments [l, m] and [m, r]
  // note that m is processed twice and requires extra recursion
  // however this eliminates the extra coding needed to handle
  // the case where m and m + 1 are not consecutive
  return findMissing(arr, l, m).concat(findMissing(arr, m, r));
}
var result = findMissing(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is nice but it will not report missing values at the beginning of the array. (Eg. `s00` is missing.)

Comment: @rici you are correct, I missed that part (and the case of having an array with exactly one item). One could handle these cases outside the recursive portion.

Answer (score 1):

This version fills an array with all possible values and then picks the ones missing:

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];

var fullArray = Array(71).fill().map((item, index) => "s"+(""+(0 + index)).padStart(2,"0"));

var missingValues = fullArray.filter( ( el ) => !arr.includes( el ) );

console.log(missingValues);
```

With a bit more of readability and reusability:

```js
var arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];

var prependString = "s";
var numberOfDigits = 2;
var initialNumber = 0;
var finalNumber = 70;

var fullArray = Array(finalNumber - initialNumber + 1)
    .fill()
    .map((item, index) => prependString+(""+(initialNumber + index)).padStart(numberOfDigits,"0"));

var missingValues = fullArray.filter( ( el ) => !arr.includes( el ) );

console.log(missingValues);
```

Comment: funny solution, at least it teaches a lot about array's methods

Comment: `With a bit more of readability and reusability:` it's a bit strange to see this sort of mix between functional and non-functional approach. For the sake of information - in order to be purely functional, you won't have the various "parameters" defined on top. Instead, you'll have, say, a function `prepend` that takes a parameter for what to prepend and you will pass in `"s"`. E.g., `prepend = prefix => string => prefix + string` and then you will pass `prepend("s")` as a mapping function. This way, you are not reliant on outside data and your functions remain pure.

Comment: @vlaz Thanks for your comment. How would you "pass" ``initialNumber`` to the mapping function in such case? ``var prepend = (prefix, initialNumber, numberOfDigits, index) => "" + prefix+(""+(initialNumber+index)).padStart(numberOfDigits,"0");`` as mapping definition and ``prepend("s", 0, 2, index)`` as mapping call doesn't seem to make it more pure. This funciton relies on some "configuration" that I wanted to put together at the beginning.

Comment: @Bernat the pure function approach would be to use several smaller function and/or curry it. All resulting in a chain of processing. likely involving [functional composition](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-function-composition-20dfb109a1a0). If you break out the function into smaller ones, it saves you from having a "global" variable `numberOfDigits = 2` as you'll have something like `pad(2)` and then the `prefix("s")` I mentioned. By composing you'd have `padAndPrefix = compose(prefix("s"), pad(2))`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript version of the C program above, one that allows for sequences of missing elements.

```
var util = require( 'util' );

//  Array of data.
var arr = [
        1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
    30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
    40, 41, 42, 43,         46, 47, 48, 49,
    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
    60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70
];
var arr_len = arr.length;

//  Empty array?
if (arr_len == 0)
{
    console.log(
        util.format(
            "No elements." ));
    process.exit( 0 );
}

//  Pre-check.
var lim = arr[arr_len - 1] - (arr_len - 1);
if (lim == 0)
{
    printf(
        "No missing elements.\n" );
    return 0;
}

//  Initialize binary search.
var lo  = 0;
var hi  = arr_len;
var mid = 0;

//  Search metadata.
var cnt = 0;
var prv = 0;
var val = 0;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < arr_len && cnt < lim; i++)
{
    //  Get mid point of search.
    mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;

    //  Get array value, adjust and do comparisons
    val = arr[ mid ] - cnt;
    if (val === mid)
        lo = mid + 1;
    if (val > mid)
        hi = mid - 1;

    //  Have we found something?
    if (lo > hi)
    {
        //  Yes.  Divide and conquer.
        hi  = arr_len;
        prv = cnt;
        cnt = arr[ lo ] - lo;

        //  Report missing element(s).
        console.log(
            util.format(
                "Missing %d elements @ arr[ %d ] == %d, probes = %d",
                cnt - prv,
                lo,
                arr[ lo ],
                i + 1 ));
    }
}

console.log(
    util.format(
        "Probes: %d",
        i ));
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution is to join all elements of an array into a string and then search inside that string.

Here is a solution that takes an array (ordered or unordered, works fine in any case) with any pattern (no hard-coded s0x pattern needed):

```js
    const arr = ["s00","s01","s02","s03","s04","s05","s07","s08","s09","s10","s11","s12","s13","s14","s17","s19","s20","s21","s22","s24","s25","s26","s27","s28","s30","s32","s33","s34","s36","s38","s39","s41","s43","s44","s45","s46","s47","s48","s49","s50","s51","s52","s53","s54","s55","s56","s58","s60","s61","s62","s63","s64","s65","s67","s69","s70"];
    let firstIndex = Number(arr[0].replace(/\D/, ''));
    let lastIndex = Number(arr[arr.length-1].replace(/\D/, ''));
    let separator = ',';
    
    let arrString = separator + arr.join(separator) + separator;
    for (let i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
     let element = arr[0].slice(0, arr[0].length - String(i).length) + i;
    
     if (arrString.indexOf(separator + element + separator) < 0) {
   console.log(element)
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array of Booleans to keep track of items present:-

```
let numbers = arr.map(s => +s.slice(1)); // Convert to numbers
let maximum = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); // Get the maximum
let missing = Array(maximum).fill(true); // start with all missing
let answer = numbers.reduce((p, c) => (p[c] = false, p), missing); // set to false if there
answer.forEach((e,i) =>  (e && console.log(i + " seems to be missing"))); // show answer
```

Also works for randomly arranged numbers.

Comment: If you are only interested in the first missing item(s), the array length can be the same as arr's. Then just ignore arr's values too large for this array.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you know there are no duplicates and that the entries are in order, a fairly simple process would be to start by checking the number of elements in the list.

The length of arr should be equal to the number of consecutive elements, yes?

*** Caveat: If the elements are not sorted or there could be duplicates, this won't work, of course.

Assuming the conditions apply then a simple binary search would find the first missing element.

After that, it is a divide and conquer, with the binary search being limited to the upper part of the search space in order to find the next missing element.  A recursive algorithm would be easy to understand, but you could also do it in a single function.

Note that the elements contain a relationship between their list indices.  In your binary search, if "s08" is in element seven, then you know there is a missing element earlier in the array.

The binary search is fairly easy, and would probably benefit from a less naive way of comparison as well, since the elements are a fixed field string.

The adjustment for missing elements is fairly easy, as well.  Each missing element shifts the rest of the elements one index left, so that turns into a simple integer operation.

Seriously?  It isn't that hard:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

#define ARY_SZ  68

static
int arr[ARY_SZ] =
{
        1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
    30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
    40, 41, 42, 43,     45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
    60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70
};

int
main(
    void )
{
    int     i,
            lim,
            lo,
            hi,
            mid,
            val,
            cnt;

    /*  Pre-check.  */
    lim = arr[ARY_SZ - 1] - (ARY_SZ - 1);
    if (lim == 0)
    {
        /*  No missing elements.    */
        printf(
            "No missing elements.\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    /*  Initialize binary search.   */
    lo  = 0;
    hi  = ARY_SZ;
    cnt = 0;

    /*  For (at most) the number of array elements, do: */
    for (i = 0; i < ARY_SZ && cnt < lim; i++)
    {
        /*  Get mid point of search.    */
        mid = lo + hi >> 1;

        /*  Get array value, adjust and do comparisons. */
        val = arr[ mid ] - cnt;
        if (val == mid)
            lo = mid + 1;
        if (val > mid)
            hi = mid - 1;

        if (lo > hi)
        {
            /*  Report missing element. */
            printf(
                "Missing element @ arr[ %d ] == %d, probes = %d\n",
                lo,
                arr[ lo ],
                i );

            /*  Divide and conquer. */
            hi   = ARY_SZ;
            cnt += 1;
        }
    }

    printf(
        "Probes = %d\n",
        i - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

The results of compiling this C code and running it:

```
Missing element @ arr[ 0 ] == 1, probes = 5
Missing element @ arr[ 43 ] == 45, probes = 11
Missing element @ arr[ 67 ] == 70, probes = 16
Probes = 16
```

So, no linear search necessary, and a maximum of 16 probes required to find the three missing elements.

Comment: It's not at all clear how '*the binary search [is] limited to the upper part of the search space in order to find the next missing element*' when there are possibly missing elements spread throughout the array. You *might* only have to search half the space on an iteration, but you also might have to iterate on both.

Comment: *"Assuming the conditions apply then a simple binary search would find the first missing element."* - what do you want to binary-search for? The missing element? How do you want to search for it using binary search, if you don't know what the missing element is?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: If one is entitled to assume that the array is sorted and contains no duplicates, and for some values `start` and `end`, `arr[end]==arr[start]-start+end`, then all elements from `start` to `end`, inclusive, are present.  If `arr[end] < arr[start]-start+end`, then checking `arr[(start+end)/2]` against `arr[start]-start+(start+end/2)` will either indicate that an element is missing in the range `start`..`(start+end)/2`, or that an element must be missing in the range `(start+end/2)` to `end`.

Comment: @supercat That's all good and nice, but it still doesn't tell me what number to pass as an argument to the `binarySearch` function, and what I should do with the returned index?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: There are ways of doing binary searches other than the `binarySearch` function.  The thing to look for is the value of `arr[i]-i-arr[0]`.  To find the first missing item, look for the lowest value of `i` for which that yields 1.  To find the second missing item, look for the lowest value where that yields 2, etc.

Comment: @supercat Have you really inferred all of that from the answer that we are discussing? That seems a bit strange to me, because the answer doesn't contain a single snippet of code or anything remotely resembling arrays or indices. You don't have to convince *me* that some binary-search-like algorithm for this problem exists - I think this is indeed the case. I just don't see how this answer describes anything like an algorithm at all. It seems just like a diffuse enumeration of statements saying "this is fairly easy", "that is fairly easy", "everything is fairly easy"...

Comment: Seriously?  It's not that hard:

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: Code added, though I used C as the most efficient way of demonstrating it.