# Convert function just using array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine I have the following array of objects:

```
 const object = [
  {Name: "A", Nr: "01"},
  {Name: "B", Nr: "02"},
  {Name: "C", Nr: "04"},
  {Name: "D", Nr: "06"},
  {Name: "E", Nr: "07"},
 ];
```

And I have the following function:

```
const findCurrentNumber = (obj) => {
    let numbers = obj.map((a) => {
      return parseInt(a["Nr"]);
    });

    numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let current = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
    for (let i = numbers.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      if (numbers[i - 1] !== numbers[i] - 1) current = numbers[i - 1];
    }

    return current + 1;
  };
```

I will get the value 3 as return. But I want to do the same just using array methods (map, sort, reduce etc). I was trying and I stopped here:

```
const obj = object.map(a => parseInt(a["Nr"])).sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

I don't know how to continue from the part I declared the **current** variable.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the last for loop?

Comment: It looks like the for loop is just grabbing the element at [0] and adding 1 to it.  Not sure why you need a loop to do that

Comment: @Taplar it *might* be the first element or not. It's the last element (in regards to the loop, it's going as close as possible to the beginning of the array) that is *not* `1` larger than the element following it.

Comment: @Taplar I edited the question, I guess you can have a better understanding now

Comment: @Polalas actually, it's even less clear. You don't even have numbers, you're not *adding* one to `current`, you're doing *string concatenation*. I'm still not sure what the point is.

Comment: @Taplar for `[1, 2, 4]` it's going to end up with `current = 2` (index `1`)

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not doing string concatenation as I'm converting to int before.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Still, what is the idea? Find the first gap in the numbering?

Comment: @VLAZ that is right! Find the first gap

Comment: Nvm, I missed that part of the if is doing `[i] - 1`. @VLAZ yeah I plugged it into a fiddle and saw I misread the logic.

Comment: @Taplar https://jsbin.com/zixoyegohe/edit?js,console

Comment: If you want to find the first gap that would be something like, `object.map(a => parseInt(a["Nr"])).sort((a, b) => a - b).find((elem, index, arr) => index < arr.length - 1 && elem != arr[index + 1]);`

Comment: @Taplar this doesn't work! Look at this example: https://jsbin.com/womivek/edit?js,console

where the return should be 4 and not 1

Comment: @Polalas typo on my part. `elem != arr[index + 1]` should be `elem + 1 != arr[index + 1]`.  It returns 4 correctly then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an approach for [How to write the code with less time complexity for finding the missing element in given array range?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942576/1447675) and take the numerical values of `Nr`.

```js
function getMissing(array) {
    var min = array[0],
        max = array[0],
        missing = new Set;
    
    array.forEach(v => {
        if (missing.delete(v)) return;                   // if value found for delete return
        if (v < min) while (v < --min) missing.add(min); // add missing min values
        if (v > max) while (v > ++max) missing.add(max); // add missing max values
    });
    return missing.values().next().value;                // take the first missing value
}

const
    data = [{ Name: "A", Nr: "01" }, { Name: "B", Nr: "02" }, { Name: "C", Nr: "04" }, { Name: "D", Nr: "06" }, { Name: "E", Nr: "07" }],
    first = getMissing(data.map(({ Nr }) => +Nr));

console.log(first);
```

Classic approach. By checking an ordered array of numbers and get the one where the next value has a delta of more than one. Finally add one for the missing number.

```js
const
    data = [{ Name: "A", Nr: "01" }, { Name: "B", Nr: "02" }, { Name: "C", Nr: "04" }, { Name: "D", Nr: "06" }, { Name: "E", Nr: "07" }],
    first = 1 + data
        .map(({ Nr }) => +Nr)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .find((l, i, { [i + 1]: r = Number.MAX_VALUE }) => r >= l + 2);

console.log(first);
```

Comment: Thank you, Nina! I appreciate you showing me this method with less time complexity. I will not set your response as the questions' answer because that is not specifically what I wanted, but I really appreciate! Danke

Comment: [I commented on the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942303/how-to-write-the-code-with-less-time-complexity-for-finding-the-missing-element/50942576#comment114582634_50942576) but I'd like to bring attention to the same thing here. This first algorithm is actually `O(n*m)` where `n` is the input size and `m` is the largest gap between the numbers. For example `[1, 3]` will only generate `2` but `[0, 9001]` will generate the entire range from `1` to `9000` because of the gap between the two elements.

Comment: @NinaScholz in this example https://jsbin.com/velobip/edit?js,console it doesn't return the exact value it was expect to return, which is 2

Comment: @Polalas, thank you for the hint. i changed the items, now it checks the next value or a max value.